# IIS SSL/TLS How to enable Session resumption

Tags: ssl, iis, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

I've been fighting some random IOExceptiosn over SSL which we believe to be SSL handshake issues when dealing with a lot of connections at once.

I read that Session resumption might help with this.

Googling I found some information on adding a registry key and using some power shell commands to enable it on Windows and IIS

https://forums.iis.net/t/1239418.aspx?How+to+enable+TLS+session+resumption+or+Optimize+TLS+handshake+on+Windows+2016+

using https://ssllabs.com to test it still shows disabled so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or even if this is the correct approach to resolving the issues.